# ReactJS: How to best handle JSON response of newly created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, reactjs

I have three React components: the first is a container (`NoteContainer` component) which is responsible for rendering my objects (`Note` component) in the UI. The data is obtained as JSON via AJAX GET. The last component is a form (`NoteForm`) which creates new objects (via AJAX POST).

The response from the POST is only the JSON representation of the newly created object, not the JSON for all of the objects.

Should the `NoteForm` send the JSON response from creating a new object to the `NoteContainer` which would append it to its state.data and re-render , or should the `NoteContainer` request the full list of objects and update its state date entirely?

I would presume the first way is better since it does not require requesting data which is already present in the state of NoteContainer. However, I'm still not sure of the "best" way to handle this. Should I give `NoteContainer` another function, something like `addNewNote`, which would take the JSON data from the NoteForm and append it to state.data?

I'm new to React so I apologize if this is not a clear question. Here are my components:

```
var NoteContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url, 
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    var noteNodes = this.state.data.map(function(note){
      return (
        <Note title={note.title} body={note.body} />
      );
    });
    return (<div className='noteContainer'>{noteNodes}</div>);
  }
});

var Note = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="note" >
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <p>{this.props.body}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var NoteForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {'title': '', 'body': ''}
  },
  handleTitleChange: function(e){
    this.setState({title: e.target.value});
  },
  handleBodyChange: function(e){
    this.setState({body: e.target.value});
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var note = {
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body};
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: note,
      success: function(data){
        // Send data to NoteContainer? 
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
  });
},

  render: function(){
    return (
      <form> 
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Title'
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleTitleChange} />
        <textarea onChange={this.handleBodyChange}>
          {this.state.body}
        </textarea>

      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: https://code-cartoons.com/a-cartoon-guide-to-flux-6157355ab207#.1hrf7zd7u - https://blog.risingstack.com/react-js-best-practices-for-2016/

Answer (score 2):

What @xCrZx is suggesting is that you pull the state outside of the individual components and have a one or more top-level stores to maintain state. The simplest (i.e. "vanilla") example of this would be if your `NoteContainer` was a parent of `NoteForm`. Then you could simply pass a callback from `NoteContainer` to `NoteForm`:

```
var NoteContainer = React.createClass({
  createNote: function() {
    ...
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      ...
      <NoteForm createNote={this.createNote}>
      ...
    );
  }
});

var NoteForm = React.createClass({
  props: {
    createNote: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      ...
        onClick={this.props.createNote}
      ...
    );
  }
});
```

However, that of course only works if the relationship actually exists. Now let's take a look at [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs), where you create central stores (and actions to go with them) to keep data, and components "listen" to the stores.

```
var NoteActions = Reflux.createActins([
  'createNote',
  'getNotes'
]);

var NoteStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [NoteActions],
  init: {
    // Notes is an empty array by default
    this.notes = [];
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      notes: this.notes
    };
  },
  onCreateNote: function(noteFormData) { ...POST here, save note JSON to this.notes on success... },
  onGetNotes: function() { ..GET here for the initial load...}
});

var NoteForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    ...
      onClick={NoteActions.createNote(noteFormData)}
    ...
  }
});

var NoteContainer = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(NoteStore)],
  componentDidMount: function() {
    NoteActions.getNotes();
  },
  render: function() {
    return: function() {
      .. same that you have now using this.state.notes
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this is starting to make sense. Highly recommend looking through the Reflux (or Redux, similar but different) examples.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I'll really need to dig into Reflux or Redux if it helps solve / simplify this kind of use case. Would you mind looking over my answer of handling it without Reflux/Redux, and without making one component a child of the other? I would appreciate the feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to keep all notes in global state and add new entities there one by one when needed. It can be achieved with help of global stores, like Redux or Reflux.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keep all nodes in a global state and add new entities". I'll look into Redux and Reflux, but it in the context of vanilla ReactJS, what would be the best way to go about this?